# Thinkpad x200 ethernet cant connect to cisco modem (BUT to router it connects)

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, thinkpad

I got a problem with my x200 thinkpad.

When I connect it with my modem/router thingy (http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/modem_DPC3208.html), the connection it not established. Its get stuck at the "Requesting an ethernet network adress for "Wired-Connection1"-bit . 
Strangely my pc does(bout 1 year old hardware) connect to the cisco without problems..

I got debian stable running on my x200, but that is not the problem. I installed windows 7 on it, and the lan connection did not work either with the cisco. Here is the confusing part: The x200 DOES connect at the speedport-router(Telekom-Speedport-W724V) at my other place, so the lan-card is not damaged or something. The LEDs are blinking too...

This is what i extracted from the /var/log/syslog:
http://pastebin.com/LP894Dwa 
(I disconnected the lan cable later, it says so in the log too)

Also this is the output of $ ip addr show

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group      default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1f:16:12:79:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:21:6a:0b:39:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

It is a really strange problem. The LAN-card of the laptop got blinking LEDs and everything and is working on the router but NOT on the cisco modem I have liked above.

Maybe the log file I liked in the pastebin-link above can help..

Comment: Your modem cannot provide a dynamic IP address for your Thinkpad. Cable modems typically have no router services.  ADSL modems typically do have router services (e.g. DHCP, NAT, DNS, firewall).  The Telekom Speedport router can provide a dynamic IP address for your Thinkpad because it has a DHCP server. *"Strangely my pc does"* -- It's probably configured with a static IP address.  You should install a router between your modem and Thinkpad for DHCP as well as NAT and firewall. *"It is a really strange problem"* -- No, it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I currently have no router to install between the modem and the thinkpad. How would one configure my thinkpad that it works with my modem?

Comment: Is that the modem your provider gave you, or is it something you got yourself?

Comment: @sawdust: but the CMTS (Cable Modem Termination System) does serve DHCP requests. Connecting the laptop straight to the modem should result in the laptop getting a dynamic public/private IP from the CMTS unless it's filtering MAC addresses, which is the norm.

Comment: since superuser.com seems to bug at my end I cant answer the replies(not enough rep) to my question and have to create a new answer. geewee yes, that is the modem my provider gave me , also I can check this evening if my mac adress is blocked and will keep you updated. Since the cisco only has 1 LAN box and I have like 3 devices which need internet I am considering buying a router which has wlan and 4 lan slots easy. FreudianSlip thanks for the answer, but that is not the case. the cisco works with the same cable and another laptop.

Comment: Late to the party here, but does the router provide 'auto-crossover' on it's ports and maybe the cisco doesn't? In which case, a crossover ethernet cable may be needed.

Comment: Its not a bug. You have one registered and one non registered account. You will want to use the contact us link to request they be merged.

Comment: @FreudianSlip please see my comment above yours

Comment: @bers not sure what you mean - i'm talking about the actual ethernet cable that goes between the ports - the router probably has auto-crossover enabled on it's port so you can use any ethernet cable, whereas the cisco may not have, so you'll need to do the crossover with a special crossover cable.

Comment: @FreudianSlip The cisco modem works with every pc and laptop that I have except the thinkpad. I dont think that the cable is the issue since it works with my other machines. (Are we talking about the same thing here? I mean the cable which goes between the laptop and the modem)

Comment: @bers yeah, I'm sure we're talking about the right thing.  I'm not sure if the x200 has auto-crossover (would be a massive omission if it didn't .. it's not that old).  When you plug the cable in between the 2 devices, do both link lights illuminate?

Comment: @FreudianSlip ill check that when i am back at home and keep you updated. thanks for the answers so far :)